# How to combine regex and string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have this hardcoded regex

```
/^ *\d+(?:\.\d+)+ *Country/
```

How can I change it so that `Country` comes from a string variable, and another variable would be `/^ *\d+(?:\.\d+)+ */`, then somehow concatenate it so it becomes

```
/^ *\d+(?:\.\d+)+ *Country/
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
 var re = new RegExp('^ *\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+ *'+  country);
```